# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file:/tmp/spark-d48e6576/scratch_hive_2016-12-28_10-47-18_519_1, expected: hdfs://nameservice1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to parse JSON log file with spark and append to external hive table.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val local: String = args(0)
val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Proxy")
val ctx = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(ctx)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json("group-8_instance-48_2016-10-  19-16-54.log")
df.registerTempTable("proxy_par_tmp")
val results_transaction =sqlContext.sql("SELECT type,time,path,protocol,protocolSrc, duration, status, serviceContexts,customMsgAtts,correlationId, legs FROM proxy_par_tmp where type='transaction'")
val two = saveFile(results_transaction).toDF()
two.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("lzwpp_ushare.proxy_par")
ctx.stop
}

def saveFile(file:DataFrame): RDD[String]={

val five =file.map { t =>( t(0).toString + "~" +t(1).toString + "~" +t(2).toString + "~" +t(3).toString + "~" +t(4).toString
  + "~" +t(5).toString + "~" +t(6).toString + "~" +t(7).toString + "~" +t(8).toString + "~" +t(9).toString
  + "~"+ t(10).toString) }

five
}
```

Also tried with

```
  two.saveAsTable("lzwpp_ushare.proxy_par",SaveMode.Append)
```

The problem is when I try the same thing with Hive managed table it works fine but not for External table.
Spark-shell as well as spark-submit throws the same error. 
It writes to HDFS

Thanks.